# Return array values from function for use in next function

Tags: arrays, node.js, function, callback, return

I have this function:

```
getSlaves: function() {
  fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', function(err, data) {
    var array = data.toString().split("\n");
    for(i in array) {
      if (array[i].indexOf('slave') > -1){
        var workerNo = array[i].slice(-1);
        var ip = array[i].split(" ");
        console.log(ip);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

At present it writes this to console:

```
[ '192.168.11.1', 'slave1' ]
[ '192.168.11.2', 'slave2' ]
[ '192.168.11.3', 'slave3' ]
```

I want this to return so I can use it in another function. I've tried adding `return(ip)` and `callback(ip)` to the method but that doesn't work.How can I return these values so they can be used by an different function?

Comment: have you tried declaring the variable outside of the function so that it is global, then setting it in the function?

Comment: You may also want to have [tag:javascript].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You need to build a list of `ip` values and return them all at once. Or use function generator and yield the values (<-- not sure if this is a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

**Way you can pass the array of ips into a callback**

```
function getSlaves(callback) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
    else {
        fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', function (err, data) {
            var array = data.toString().split("\n");
            let data = [];//to store ips
            for (i in array) {
                if (array[i].indexOf('slave') > -1) {
                    var workerNo = array[i].slice(-1);
                    var ip = array[i].split(" ");
                    data.push(ip);
                }
            }
            callback(undefined, rarr);
        });
    }
}
```

**How do you access the array**

```
function yourFunc(){
    getSlaves((err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```